# Aframe Text lookAt Screen

Tags: javascript, aframe

This might sound stupid simple, but has taken me an awful lot of time to find answers. Hope someone here able to shed some enlightment.

I have a skybox using A-Frame v1.0.4, and a look at component v0.8.0, and am able to display text as a child of a plane (that works as marker), and is always looking towards camera.

Is there a way to make the text to always face front (towards the screen) instead of wrapping it into perspective when we rotate the camera?

Some illustration to make it clearer:

[image: when facing dead front of camera, is all ok]

When nearing the left side of the browser

[image]

I'm hoping to make it look like this

[image]

Code is simple stupid, following sample from billboarding component
https://github.com/blairmacintyre/aframe-look-at-billboard-component

```
<a-entity id="monster" geometry="primitive: box" material="src: url(monster.png)" billboard></a-entity>
```

This dont work tho..

Comment: Oh right, also I have to put the text as a child of the marker, since there will be an awful lot of them. I cant put it as a child of camera.. anyone?

Comment: please try adding some code, it would be easier to suggest changes than writing a complete code for you.

Comment: @ModularEconomy if its a non-vr maybe it would be simpler to do the icons as overlay (html canvas over the a-frame layer). Otherwise i believe you should look into [billboarding](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-billboards.html).

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thanks so much.. Billboarding is the answer.. https://github.com/blairmacintyre/aframe-look-at-billboard-component seems like what i need, however when tried, works just like normal lookat component